# Is it possible to use " every second Saturday" instead of "every other Saturday"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, differences, phrase-usage

Is it possible to use " every second Saturday" instead of "every other Saturday"?

What about "every two Saturdays"? Is it same as "every other Saturday"?

Comment: Second is fine, two is wrong (which two?).

Comment: "every second Saturday" would imply the *second Saturday* of *every* month.  IMO, "every other Saturday" does not mean the same thing as "every second Saturday".

Comment: Agreed with @Kristina . Even if it we stretch it to mean two such Saturdays occur in a 4-week period, those Saturdays must be the 2nd and the 4th; they could *not* be the 1st and 3rd (whereas "*every other Saturday*" could be either the 1st  & 3rd or the 2nd & 4th, depending on when the first event happened.)

Comment: I would find it ambiguous, since it's also likely to mean every day that's the second Tuesday ***of the month***. Every ***two*** Saturdays just sounds weird.

Comment: I would say *biweekly on Saturdays*

Comment: Alex W, the words you recommended are clear and seem very official. Thank you. I wondered if every other day and every two days could be applied in other ways. Thank all of you:)

Comment: The "every two ...s" construction works well with general units of time/measurement and, to me, it would mean the same as "every other ..." in those cases (minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years/inches/feet/etc), but as mentioned above, "every two" + a specific day [Saturdays] or specific time [midnights] sounds weird, although I'm not sure that it's necessarily "wrong." If you wanted to use "every two" in a sentence with a specific day in mind, you could perhaps say "We meet on Saturday[s?], every two weeks." (not sure if I'd pluralize 'Saturday' or not in this example, sorry). @junepark

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'd think "every other" if somebody said "we could meet every second sunday", but "2nd of the month" if somebody said "it's on every second sunday of <month>". I'd assume the first one for most circumstances.

Comment: Interesting dialog!! this is a real bugaboo with me because I know of 3 businesses in my area in which claim to be open every other Saturday. I have often mentioned to them that this is confusing to customers and, when I ask the employees what it means, they are clearly confused by the quesiton and just tell me when they are open. I just can't believe a business would not recieve many customers complaining about this practice and resolve the problem. From everything I've read, the correct way to approach this is to sate: We are open on the 2nd and 4th Saturday of every month. DONE!!! No confus

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I would interpret "every second Saturday" to implicitly mean "every second Saturday [of the month]".
However, I think this is more an error of interpretation, than it actually being incorrect.

"Every other Saturday" seems to be immune to such misinterpretations, and I'd favor using that instead, if only to prevent possible misunderstandings.